# Reducing the resolution of a NumPy array for fractional numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have a `NumPy` array `(200,2700)` and I want to reduce resolution of columns(200). I mean, if my reducing value is 4 (`integration_value=4`), my new array will be `(50,2700)` and my new array will be obtained with the sum of every four columns.

I use this integrator function to get array:

```
def integrator(data, rows, cols):
    return data.reshape(rows, (data.shape[0]//rows), cols, (data.shape[1]//cols)).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=2)


newarray = integrator(array, 2700, 200//integration_value)
```

But this code is only valid for divisible numbers. For example, I get error when I select `integration_value=7` because when I divide 200 with 7, it's equal to 28,57.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The value of `200//7` (it's an integer division) is `28`, not `28.57`.  What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have partial rows or columns. Make sure to round, floor, or ceil to guarantee even partitioning

Answer (score 0):

> I get error when I select integration_value=7 because when I divide 200 with 7, it's equal to 28,57.

You can use `math.floor` to ensure it is always an integer

```
import math

newarray = integrator(array, 2700, math.floor(200//integration_value))
```